# Não retorna erro nenhum de uma função AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Retorna um `alert` vazio quando uso esse código(peguei na internet):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{   
$(".busca").keyup(function() 
{
    var busca = jQuery(".busca").val();
    if(busca.length >= 1) 
    {

        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "resultado.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: "busca=" + busca,

            success: function(response)
            {
                jQuery("#retorno").html(response);
            },
            error: function(request, status, erro)
            {
                alert("Problema ocorrido: " + status + "\nDescição: " + erro);
                alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia, O erro pode estar acontecendo por causa do tipo do retorno, se não for retornar uma partial em HTML... para isso o método no seu código também precisa estar retornando HTML , se o seu código estiver retornando um JSON, teria que ser dataType: "JSON" ... e assim por diante...
Como está no seu código?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz vários simulados utilizando o próprio código que você postou (com uma pequena alteração de em vez de exibir um *alert*, a mensagem seria exibida no próprio *div #retorno*), e a única situação em que isso ocorreu, foi quando acessei o arquivo direto pelo protocolo **file:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]